# Most efficient way to aggregate matrix based on grouping variable

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, aggregate, grouping

Is there a more efficient way of doing the below, i.e., aggregating a matrix based on grouping variable?

```
mat <- matrix( sample(2:100, 50), ncol=10, nrow=5)
colnames(mat) <- c(LETTERS[1:10])
rownames(mat) <- 1:5
mat.m <- melt(mat)
mat.m$Group <- NA

df <- cbind( data.frame(ID=LETTERS[1:10]), data.frame(Group=c("Plant","Fish","Rodent","Fish","Rodent","Bird","Plant","Fish","Bird","Bird")))
df$ID <- as.character(df$ID)
df$Group <- as.character(df$Group)

for( i in 1:nrow(mat.m) ){
  for( j in 1:nrow(df) ){
    mat.m$Group[i] <- ifelse(mat.m$Var2[i]==df$ID[j], df$Group[j], mat.m$Group[i])
  }
} 

mat.agg <- dcast(mat.m, Var1~Group, fun.aggregate = sum)

mat.agg
   Bird Fish Plant Rodent
1  154  215    43     83
2  122   44   132    163
3  177  211   118    120
4  206  125    89     92
5  125  269   151    156
```

I have very large matrices, so I would like to know if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` the 'ID' by 'Group' in 'df', loop through the `list` with `vapply` subset the columns of 'mat' based on the 'ID', use `rowSums` to get the sum of each row to get a `matrix` as output.

```
vapply(split(df$ID, df$Group), function(x) 
             rowSums(mat[,x]), numeric(nrow(mat)))
```

NOTE: The `split` method is fast and as we are using `vapply` it also increases the efficiency.

Comment: How if df$ID only contains one of the potential groups? 
Then I get `Error in rowSums(mat[, 1]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`

Comment: @jO.  Perhaps you need `rowSums(mat[,x, drop = FALSE])`